# Monitering Bandwidth over lan

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, internet, bandwidth

I am using ccproxy to moniter which computer in my house is using how much bandwidth. I created an account and set it to "Permit Only" and Authentication type "IP address". I created new account but it is not showing any thing on the green grid. What should I do? Am I missing something? I have given the IP address shown in Network Manager of Windows XP.

Please Help.